# Trying to print the factorial of a number with recursion using javascript but its not giving the expected output

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorial

Trying to print the factorial of a number with recursion using javascript but its not giving the expected output.

```
function factorialRecursion(n){
return n * factorialRecursion(n - 1);
}
factorialRecursion(6);
```

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (`enter code here`index.html:3), :1:28)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)
    at factorialRecursion (eval at factorial (index.html:3), :3:13)

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: Seriously, one statement saying my code doesn't give expected output, same in the title and the question, and no more information. What solution are you expecting? Something like *Then make it give the expected output*?

Answer (score 1):

The stack overflows because there is no **base case**.

- to calculate `factorial(6)`, you need to know the answer to `factorial(5)`
- to calculate `factorial(5)`, you need to know the answer to `factorial(4)`
- ...
- to calculate `factorial(1)`, you need to know the answer to `factorial(0)`
- to calculate `factorial(0)`, you need to know the answer to `factorial(-1)`
- to calculate `factorial(-1)`, you need to know the answer to `factorial(-2)`
- ...

Above we see the original program just continues `n - 1` infinitely, until the stack overflows.

A fix to your program might look like -

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n <= 0)           // <-- base case
    return 1
  else                  // <-- inductive case (n > 0)
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
}

console.log(factorial(6))
// 720
```